# Parsed word segment in second function can not be compared to string in latex?

Tags: macros, makeindex, parsing

I would like to parse words by removing always the last segment ("1. Book1 p3" becomes "1. Book1" or "Book2 p4" becomes "Book2"). This I achieved with the function `\FirstPart`. Now, I would like to use the return argument of `\FirstPart` in the function `\foo` in order to do a string comparison. If the input argument agrees to the ifthenelse test, it should return the corresponding key (in the example if the input is "1. Book p.2", the return should be "01Category"). So I tested `\foo{\FirstPart{1. Book p.2}}`, however I always get FALSE as a return value. I think there is a type mismatch, however I do not know how to resolve this issue. In the end I want to use `\foo` for specifying the sorting order of `\index` (makeindex package) (one entry in a custom environment would look like: `\index{\foo{\FirstPart{#1}}@\FirstPart{#1}!#1}`. Could anybody help me?

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\FirstPart[1]{#1}%
\newcommand\firstwords{}%
\def\firstwords#1 #2 #3\@nil{\if\relax#3\relax
    #1\relax
    \else
    \foo{#1 #2\relax}
    \fi}    
\makeatother

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1. Book}}
    {01Category}
     {FALSE}}

\begin{document}
    
    \foo{\FirstPart{1. Book p.2}}\\
    \foo{1. Book}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: In your MWE the command `\firstwords` is defined but not used anywhere...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Would you be interested in receiving a LuaLaTeX-based solution?

Comment: `LaTeX3` could be also used...

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you want to achieve. Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\firstwordscase}{mmm}
 {
  \ise_firstwordscase:enn { \text_expand:n { #1 } } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \ise_firstwordscase:nnn
 {
  \__ise_firstwordscase:nnw { #2 } { #3 } #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \ise_firstwordscase:nnn { e }

\cs_new:Npn \__ise_firstwordscase:nnw #1 #2 #3 ~ #4 ~ #5 \q_stop
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #3~#4 } { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\test}{1. Book2 p3} % just for testing

\begin{document}

\firstwordscase{1. Book1 p3}{
  {1. Book1}{01Category}
  {1. Book2}{XYZ}
}{FALSE}
    
\firstwordscase{1. Book2 p3}{
  {1. Book1}{01Category}
  {1. Book2}{XYZ}
}{FALSE}
    
\firstwordscase{\test}{
  {1. Book1}{01Category}
  {1. Book2}{XYZ}
}{FALSE}

\firstwordscase{2. Book1 p1}{
  {1. Book1}{01Category}
  {1. Book2}{XYZ}
}{FALSE}
    
\end{document}
```

You can have as many case switches you want.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of variety, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It consists of two LaTeX utility macros, called `\FirstPart` and `\foo`, that make `\directlua` calls to Lua functions called, you guessed it, `FirstPart` and `foo`, respectively. Observe that because `\directlua` is expandable, `\foo{\FirstPart{1. Book p.2}}` and `\foo{1. Book}` produce the same output.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

%% Lua-side code:
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function FirstPart ( s )
  n = s:find ( "%s+%S+$" )
  tex.sprint ( s:sub ( 1 , n - 1 ) )
end

function foo ( s )
  if s == "1. Book" then 
    tex.sprint ( "01Category" )
  else 
    tex.sprint ( "FALSE" )
  end
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX-side code:
\newcommand\FirstPart[1]{\directlua{FirstPart("#1")}}
\newcommand\foo[1]{\directlua{foo("#1")}}

\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
\FirstPart{1. Book1 p3}
\FirstPart{Book2 p4}
\foo{\FirstPart{1. Book p.2}}
\foo{1. Book}
\foo{\FirstPart{Book2 p4}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a command `\foo` which only by expansion-methods tests whether its argument (after expansion and) after appending a space starts with `1.⟨space⟩Book⟨space⟩` is sufficient?

```latex
\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@Exchange,
%%    \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens, \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's leading tokens form a specific 
%% token-sequence that does not contain explicit character tokens of 
%% category 1 or 2 or 6:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{<argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                              {<a <token sequence> without explicit 
%%                                character tokens of category 1 or 2
%%                                or 6>}%
%%                              {<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case
%%                                <argument which is to be checked> has
%%                                <token sequence> as leading tokens>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case 
%%                                <argument which is to be checked>
%%                                does not have <token sequence> as
%%                                leading tokens>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[3]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {%
    % Let's nest things into \UD@firstoftwo{...}{} to make sure they are nested in braces
    % and thus do not disturb when the test is carried out within \halign/\valign:
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
      \romannumeral
      \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens#3{{}}#1#2}{}}{}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
  {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<token sequence>}%
%% Defines <internal token-check-macro> to snap everything 
%% until reaching <token sequence>-sequence and spit that out
%% nested in braces.
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner[2]{%
  \@ifdefinable#1{\long\def#1##1#2{{##1}}}%
}%
\makeatother


\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\GobbleTillFirstBookPhrase}{1. Book }%
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
   \expanded{\noexpand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1 }}%
                                {1. Book }%
                                {\GobbleTillFirstBookPhrase}%
                                {01Category}%
                                {FALSE}%
}%
\newcommand\FirstPart[1]{#1}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
Test 1: \foo{\FirstPart{1. Book p.2}}\\
Test 2: \foo{\FirstPart{1. Book p.2 some  } more text}\\
Test 3: \foo{1. Book}\\
Test 4: \foo{2. Book p. 2}\\
Test 5: \foo{1. Bookbinding}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I considered elaborating on a loop which successively removes space-separated components from the right of the argument for iteratively doing `\ifthenelse`-comparison until the string either matches the phrase `1. Book` or does not contain spaces.

But you mentioned that you wish to use this with the command `\index`. In many places arguments of the command `\index` need to be fully expandable which is not the case for *ifthen*'s `\ifthenelse`-command.

Answer (score 0):

The following is inspired by egreg's answer:

`\firstwordscase` with its 2nd argument does "text-expansion", strip off leading and trailing space tokens and then extract at most as many space-separated words as denoted by its 1st argument. Then does string-casing with the result as denoted by the 3rd and 4th argument. Several space tokens between words in the second argument collapse into a single space token. The content of a brace-group is considered a single word whereoff the surrounding brace-group is not stripped off and wherein space tokens etc are untouched.

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\errorcontextlines=100000
\cs_new:Npn \UD_ExtractFirstSpaceDelimitedArg:n #1#2 {
  \cs_new:Npn \UD_GobbleKnownFirstSpace:w #2 {}
  \cs_new:Npn \UD_GobbleFirstSpaceDelimitedArg:w ##1#2 {}
  \cs_new:Npn \UD_RemoveSecondSpaceDelimitedArg:ww ##1#2##2#2#1{{##1}#2}
  \cs_new:Npn \UD_RemoveBracesFromSpaceDelimitedArg:w ##1#2{\use_i:nn ##1}
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Loop for extracting the first space-delimited argument from list of
  %% space-separated components - the result is returned wrapped in curly braces
  %%.............................................................................
  \cs_gset:Npn \UD_ExtractFirstSpaceDelimitedArg:n ##1 {
    \exp:w \UD_ExtractFirstSpaceDelimitedLoop:n{{}{}##1#2#2#1}
  }
  \cs_new:Npn\UD_ExtractFirstSpaceDelimitedLoop:n ##1 {
    \tl_if_empty:oTF {\UD_GobbleFirstSpaceDelimitedArg:w ##1}
    { \exp_args:Nno \use:n {\exp_args:No\exp_end:}{\UD_RemoveBracesFromSpaceDelimitedArg:w ##1} }
    { \exp_args:No\UD_ExtractFirstSpaceDelimitedLoop:n{\UD_RemoveSecondSpaceDelimitedArg:ww ##1} }
  }
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Removal of the first space-delimited argument from list of space-separated
  %% components - the resulting list is returned wrapped in curly braces
  %%.............................................................................
  \cs_new:Npn \UD_RemoveFirstSpaceDelimitedArg:n ##1 {
    \exp:w \tl_if_empty:oTF {\UD_GobbleFirstSpaceDelimitedArg:w ##1#2}
    {\exp_end:{}}{\exp_args:No\exp_end:{\UD_GobbleFirstSpaceDelimitedArg:w ##1}}
  }
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Check whether brace-balanced argument starts with an explicit space-token
  %%.............................................................................
  %% \CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
  %%                                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                                    which is to be checked> does have a
  %%                                    leading explicit space-token>}%
  %%                                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                                    which is to be checked> does not have a
  %%                                    a leading explicit space-token>}%
  \cs_new:Npn \CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace ##1 {
    \exp:w \tl_if_empty:nTF {##1}
    {\exp_after:wN \exp_end: \use_ii:nn}
    { % Let's nest things into \use_i:nn{...}{} to make sure they are nested in braces
      % and thus do not disturb when the test is carried out within \halign/\valign:
      \exp_after:wN \use_i:nn \exp_after:wN {%
        \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_end:
        \exp:w \exp_after:wN \use_ii:nn
        \token_to_str:N { \UD_CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace:w#1##1#2 }{}
      }{}
    }
  }
  \cs_new:Npn \UD_CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace:w ##1#2 {
    \tl_if_empty:oTF {\use_i:nn{}##1}
    {\use_ii_i:nn{\use_i:nn}}{\use_ii_i:nn{\use_ii:nn}}
    {\exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN\exp_end:
     \exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN}
     \exp_after:wN\use_ii:nn\exp_after:wN{\token_to_str:N}
  }%
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
\exp_args:Nno\use:n{\exp_args:No\UD_ExtractFirstSpaceDelimitedArg:n}
{\exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN  \tex_ifnum:D 0=0\tex_fi:D }{~}
%%%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Loop for trimming all leading explicit space tokens from argument
%%
%%   \TrimAllLeadingSpaces{<argument>}{<tokens to prepend>}
%%
%% delivers  <tokens to prepend>{<argument>}   , but with all leading spaces of
%% <argument> removed.
%%.............................................................................
\cs_new:Npn \TrimAllLeadingSpaces #1 {
  \CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{#1}{
    \exp_args:No \TrimAllLeadingSpaces {\UD_GobbleKnownFirstSpace:w #1}
  }{ \use_ii_i:nn{{#1}} }
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Loop for trimming all trailing explicit space tokens from argument
%%
%%   \TrimAllTrailingSpaces{<argument>}{<tokens to prepend>}
%%
%% delivers  <tokens to prepend>{<argument>}   , but with all trailing spaces 
%% of <argument> removed.
%%
%% Algorithm:
%% Initate a loop with a tail-recursive macro with 3 arguments:
%% 1. <Space from previous iteration>. Initially empty.
%% 2. <Argument without trailing spaces gathered so far>. Initially empty.
%% 3. <Remaining argument to process>. Initially <Arg><space>.
%%
%% If <Remaining argument to process> is not blank:
%% Call \trimalltrailingspaces again, with
%%  <Argument without trailing spaces gathered so far>=
%%     <Argument without trailing spaces gathered so far>+<Space from previous iteration>+
%%     <Extraction of 1st space-delimited Arg from <Remaining argument to process> >;
%%  <Remaining argument to process>=<Remaining argument to process> with 1st space-delimited arg removed;
%%  <Space from previous iteration>=<explicit space token>;
%%
%% If <Remaining argument to process> is blank: 
%% Pass <Argument without trailing spaces gathered so far> as argument to
%% <tokens to prepend> .
%%.............................................................................
\cs_new:Npn \TrimAllTrailingSpaces #1 {\exp:w\UD_TrimAllTrailingSpacesLoop:www{}{}{#1~}}
\cs_new:Npn \UD_TrimAllTrailingSpacesLoop:www #1#2#3 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF {#3}{\exp_after:wN \exp_end: \use_ii_i:nn{{#2}}}{
    \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \use_ii_i:nn
    \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN {
      \UD_RemoveFirstSpaceDelimitedArg:n {#3}
    }{
      \exp_after:wN \use_ii_i:nn \exp_after:wN { \exp_after:wN {
        \exp:w \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \use_ii_i:nn
        \UD_ExtractFirstSpaceDelimitedArg:n {#3}{\exp_end: #2#1}
      }}{\UD_TrimAllTrailingSpacesLoop:www{~}}
    }
  }
}
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\cs_new:Npn \UD_ExtractWords:nn #1#2 { 
  \exp:w  \TrimAllLeadingSpaces { #2 }
          { \TrimAllTrailingSpaces }
          { \UD_ExtractWordsloop:nnnn {}{} }
          { #1 } 
}
\cs_new:Npn \UD_ExtractWordsloop:nnnn #1#2#3#4 {
%  % #1 stuff to prepend , #2 gathered so far, #3 remaining list, #4 number
  \int_compare:nNnTF {(#4)} > {(0)} 
     {
       \tl_if_empty:nTF  {#3} { \exp_end: #2 }{
         \CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{#3}{
           \exp_after:wN \use_ii_i:nn \exp_after:wN { \exp_after:wN { \UD_GobbleKnownFirstSpace:w #3 } }
           { \UD_ExtractWordsloop:nnnn {#1}{#2}}{#4}
         }{
           \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \use_ii_i:nn
           \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN { 
           \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN   {\int_eval:n {((#4)-1)}} 
           }{
             \exp_args:Nno \use:n { \exp_args:No \use_ii_i:nn } {
                \UD_RemoveFirstSpaceDelimitedArg:n {#3}
             }{
               \exp_args:No \use_ii_i:nn { \exp_after:wN {
                  \exp:w
                  \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
                  \use_ii_i:nn \UD_ExtractFirstSpaceDelimitedArg:n {#3}{\exp_end: #2#1}
               }}{
                  \UD_ExtractWordsloop:nnnn {~}
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
     {\exp_end: #2}
}
\cs_new:Npn \UD_firstwordscase:nn #1#2 {
  \exp_args:Nno \use:n { \exp_args:No\str_case:nnF } { \UD_ExtractWords:nn {#1}{#2} }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \UD_firstwordscase:nn { ne }
\cs_new:Npn \firstwordscase #1#2 { \UD_firstwordscase:ne {#1}{\text_expand:n {#2}} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\test}{1. Book2 p3} % just for testing

\begin{document}

\firstwordscase{2}{1. Book1 p3}{
  {1. Book1}{The second argument belongs to 1. Book1.}
  {1. Book2}{The second argument belongs to 1. Book2.}
}{The second argument doesn't belong to any of the further.}
    
\firstwordscase{2}{1. Book2 p3}{
  {1. Book1}{The second argument belongs to 1. Book1.}
  {1. Book2}{The second argument belongs to 1. Book2.}
}{The second argument doesn't belong to any of the further.}
    
\firstwordscase{2}{\test}{
  {1. Book1}{The second argument belongs to 1. Book1.}
  {1. Book2}{The second argument belongs to 1. Book2.}
}{The second argument doesn't belong to any of the further.}

\firstwordscase{2}{2. Book1 p1}{
  {1. Book1}{The second argument belongs to 1. Book1.}
  {1. Book2}{The second argument belongs to 1. Book2.}
}{The second argument doesn't belong to any of the further.}

\firstwordscase{2}{2. Book1 p1}{
  {2. Book1}{The second argument belongs to 2. Book1.}
  {1. Book2}{The second argument belongs to 1. Book2.}
}{The second argument doesn't belong to any of the further.}

\def\spaceimport#1{\firstwordscase{2}{2.#1#1#1#1Book1#1#1#1#1p1}}
\spaceimport{ }{
  {2. Book1}{The second argument belongs to 2. Book1.}
  {1. Book2}{The second argument belongs to 1. Book2.}
}{The second argument doesn't belong to any of the further.}


\firstwordscase{1}{1 A a i I - second argument }{
  {1}{The second argument belongs to 1.}
  {2}{The second argument belongs to 2.}
}{The second argument doesn't belong to any of the further.}

\firstwordscase{1}{2 A a i I - second argument }{
  {1}{The second argument belongs to 1.}
  {2}{The second argument belongs to 2.}
}{The second argument doesn't belong to any of the further.}

\firstwordscase{2}{1 A a i I - second argument }{
  {1 A}{The second argument belongs to 1 A.}
  {1 B}{The second argument belongs to 1 B.}
  {2 A}{The second argument belongs to 2 A.}
  {2 B}{The second argument belongs to 2 B.}
}{The second argument doesn't belong to any of the further.}

\firstwordscase{2}{2 B a i I - second argument }{
  {1 A}{The second argument belongs to 1 A.}
  {1 B}{The second argument belongs to 1 B.}
  {2 A}{The second argument belongs to 2 A.}
  {2 B}{The second argument belongs to 2 B.}
}{The second argument doesn't belong to any of the further.}

\firstwordscase{3}{1 A a i I - second argument }{
  {1 A a}{The second argument belongs to 1 A a.}
  {1 B a}{The second argument belongs to 1 B a.}
  {2 A a}{The second argument belongs to 2 A a.}
  {2 B a}{The second argument belongs to 2 B a.}
  {1 A b}{The second argument belongs to 1 A b.}
  {1 B b}{The second argument belongs to 1 B b.}
  {2 A b}{The second argument belongs to 2 A b.}
  {2 B b}{The second argument belongs to 2 B b.}
}{The second argument doesn't belong to any of the further.}

\firstwordscase{3}{ 2 B a i I - second argument }{
  {1 A a}{The second argument belongs to 1 A a.}
  {1 B a}{The second argument belongs to 1 B a.}
  {2 A a}{The second argument belongs to 2 A a.}
  {2 B a}{The second argument belongs to 2 B a.}
  {1 A b}{The second argument belongs to 1 A b.}
  {1 B b}{The second argument belongs to 1 B b.}
  {2 A b}{The second argument belongs to 2 A b.}
  {2 B b}{The second argument belongs to 2 B b.}
}{The second argument doesn't belong to to any of the further.}

\end{document}
```

[image]